# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "bucketname.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a default file that upon signup of a new account, gets send to an amazon bucket. That worked. But suddenly, without changing any code, all my tests that use this method, fail with the error:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for
>   "(bucketname).s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" port 443

What could have caused this error to show up so suddenly? The test errors all point to `obj.upload_file(drawingfile)` in the method below.

The model method that sends the file has not been changed and is:

```
def self.upload_empty_drawing(id)  # In the S3 bucket's I've granted access to my heroku domain as well as to https://<name>.c9.io (I'm programming in Cloud9, an IDE solution)
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
          credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
            Rails.application.secrets.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
            Rails.application.secrets.S3_SECRET_KEY),
          region: Rails.application.secrets.AWS_REGION
       )
  drawingfile = 'app/assets/emptyexample.xml'
  filename = "example/#{id}/example-#{id}.xml"
  obj = s3.bucket(Rails.application.secrets.S3_BUCKET_EXAMPLES).object(filename)
  obj.upload_file(drawingfile)
  Drawing.create!(organization_id: id, example_file: obj.public_url)
end
```

**Update:** I think there may be something else going on than an error in the model method. Because:

- Also my production site seems affected. I tried to sign up on my production site and got the error `We're sorry, but something went wrong`.
- Entering `heroku logs --tail` in the terminal (as I mentioned, I use Cloud9 IDE), produced the error `Unable to connect to api.heroku.com`.
- If I try to sign up on the development server, upon sign up, I get the same `connection refused` error that I mentioned/get when running my tests.
- Entering `heroku config` in the terminal, produces the error `Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and try again`.

Not sure what is going on ... !? Any ideas how to find out the problems, are appreciated.

Comment: where have you specified your access key/secret keys to be used by the application...kindly share :)

Comment: This is in `/config/secrets.yml`. But I don't see how this could be causing the problem, since this has worked for over a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in touch with the IDE that I use for writing my code. They were so kind to reset/reboot my account or something (not sure what they did exactly but I had "Reconnecting" on my screen for several minutes). After this, all the problems were gone. So the cause seems to have been configuration settings on the side of the IDE.

(P.S. The production side problem had a different cause: although I had set the key for a secret variable, in `secrets.yml` I had not yet defined using it in production (only in development and test))

Answer (score 0):

i had this similar problem which was related to permissons,so i updated the code in my

```
`......image.rb`............

    has_attached_file :avatar,
     :styles => 
     {
      :medium => "x300",
      :small => "150x150>",
      :thumb => "90x90>",
      },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_permissions => :private,
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS      

      .....config/initializers/paperclip.rb...............

         S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
         Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
         Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:id/:style/:filename'

      .....config/s3.yml....................
        development:
        bucket: mybucketname
        access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What code was causing the problems for you and what did you change?

Comment: i chaged my permission from public to private by using image.avatar.expiring_url(60)